# How do you solve for θ in the equation $\tan \frac{\theta}{5} + \sqrt{3} = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

$$\tan \frac{\theta}{5}  + \sqrt{3}   = 0$$

Alright so the $\frac{\theta}{5}$ is confusing me.

Would it be wrong to do

\begin{eqnarray}
\tan \frac{\theta}{5}&=&-\sqrt{3}\\
\frac{\theta}{5}&=&\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3})\\
\theta&=& 5\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3})\\
\theta&=& -\frac{5\pi}{3} + 5\pi n
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It is half correct. You forgot the fact that $\tan$ is a periodic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\tan \frac{\theta}{5}+\sqrt 3=0$$ $$\tan \frac{\theta}{5}=-\sqrt 3=-\tan \frac{\pi}{3}$$ Writing the general solution for $\theta$ as follows $$\frac{\theta}{5}=n\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$$ 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\theta=5n\pi-\frac{5\pi}{3}}}$$

Where, $n$ is any integer

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Add $n\pi$ to your answer !

Comment: I was going to do that, just wanted to make sure my algebra is correct since I haven't seen $\frac{\theta}{n}$ where $n$ is any integer before :) just wanted to make sure it was "legal" algebra

Comment: Yes, it is "legal" for sure. In fact, how much" illegal" algebra you know likely determines your "success" in math and in life !

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, except that you need to add $n \pi$ when you do $\tan^{-1}$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\frac\theta5=-\sqrt 3\iff\tan\frac\theta5=\tan\Bigl(-\frac\pi3\Bigr)\iff\frac\theta5\equiv -\frac\pi3\mod\pi\iff\theta\equiv -\frac{5\pi}3\mod 5\pi.$$